# Determine the exact value of equations involving more two trig variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

$2\cos^2x=1+\sin x$.  Determine the exact values of $x$ such that $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$.

I am experiencing problems with factoring this question.  First I started by getting everything on to the left side so: $2\cos^2x-\sin x-1=0$.  Then seeing as there are two trig variable here ($\cos$ and $\sin$), I used the pythagorean identity and replaced $2\cos^2x$ with $1-2\sin^2x$ to make it into a one variable question: $1-1-2\sin^2x-\sin x-1=0$.

By collecting like terms it then becomes $-\sin^2x-\sin x=0$.  Now you could factor these with $0$ and $-1$, but then it creates uneven brackets so this musn't work.  I don't think the quadratic formula is necessary, but I am wondering if this could be treated as a difference of squares question.

If you replace the $\sin x$ and make the question into $-x^2-x=0$ it is a little easier to look at, however I am not sure if this is the right approach.  If someone could please clarify my answer, that would be appreciated!

Comment: $2\cos^2 x = 2 - 2\sin^2 x$, not $1 - 2\sin^2 x$.

Comment: Oh okay! That makes more sense.  I know I am a visual learner, so that helped me out quite a bit.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right approach but you made a couple of errors.  You can replace $2\cos^2x = 2-2\sin^2x$ and this yields the equation

$$
2-2\sin^2x - \sin x - 1 \;\; =\;\; 0 \hspace{4pc} 2\sin^2x + \sin x - 1 \;\; =\;\; 0.
$$

Using the quadratic formula you obtain

$$
\sin x \;\; =\;\; \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{9}}{4}.
$$

Comment: The trig identity I think you're looking for is $\cos^2x + \sin^2x =1$.  You can verify this just looking at the unit circle.

Comment: After simplifying the value of x from the quadratic formula, I got x=1/2 and x=-1, is this correct?

Comment: @Ash Remember in your problem statement you replaced $\sin x$ by $x$ and solved the quadratic that way.  You need to replace $\sin x$ back in to where you replaced it originally.

Comment: Yes I did that afterwards, I just wanted to make sure if my values for x with the quadratic formula were correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:

$$2(1-\sin^2 x) - (1+\sin x) = 0 \to (1+\sin x)(2 - 2\sin x - 1) = 0\to (1+\sin x)(1-2\sin x)=0$$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

$$2\cos^2x = 1 + \sin x\to 2 - 2\sin^2x=1+\sin x \to 2\sin^2 x+\sin x - 1= 0 $$ which can be factored to give $$(2\sin x  -1)(\sin x + 1) = 0\to \sin x = -1, \sin x = \frac 12. $$ so $$x = \pi/6, 5\pi/6, 3\pi/2 $$ are the three solutions in $0 \le x \le 2\pi.$